# Remove element from DOM if a certain Json property is null or ""

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to remove an element from my DOM if a JSON Property is null or an empty string. But i cannot make it work.

Here's my code.

```
function projectJsonUi(){
    $.getJSON('/project.json',function(response){
        let foo_jpg = response.ressources.foo_jpg;
        let foo_pdf = response.ressources.foo_pdf;

            if(foo_pdf == null && foo_jpg == null){
                $("#myDiv").remove();
            }

}
```

my JSON looks like this;

```
{"ressources":{
        "foo_jpg": null,
        "foo_pdf": null,
        ...
    },...
}
```

i made a console.log() of foo_jpg i just cut it out of the code for readability, it returned null. I don't get any errors displayed. I also tried with empty string, same result. The request is valid for i have used its result in other operations successfully.

It would be nice, if someone could help me with my problem.

Comment: Please provide any errors occured. And I want to see console.log(foo_jpg) and console.log(foo_pdf) to see if they really are null because .remove() looks fine.

Comment: are you 100% sure the body of the if block is processed?

Comment: Are you sure the request is successful? Is `foo_X` an empty string or is it `null`? Does the `ressources` object exist? Is `ressources` a typo? Have you made any attempts to debug this? If so, please edit the question to include them, as there's any number of reasons for this to fail

Comment: @holydragon why use console.log when you have a debugger

Comment: @PhilippSander which debugger do you mean?

Comment: What does that JSON data look like @M.Schaper?

Comment: @holydragon javscript debugger that comes with almost every modern browser

Comment: Please provide your html code to see if the selector matches with your html.

Comment: @holydragon i did some edits hope it clarified some things :)

Comment: @M.Schaper the html is still not there.

Comment: @holydragon I checked the html, the selectors are the same, i'm not actually using the same names i posted here for discretion of my company.

Comment: @holydragon Sorry, just double checked. It somehow did not remove its child. When i remove both it finally works. Thank you.

Comment: You could also hide: `$("#myDiv").toggle(foo_pdf || foo_jpg);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently you're only checking null, not an empty string. And considering that both `null` and `""` are [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), you could just use the less verbose option of Boolean if conditions. Try using this instead:

```
if (!(foo_pdf && foo_jpg)) {
    $("#myDiv").remove();
}
```

You should also make sure your jQuery code:

```
$("#myDiv").remove();
```

Actually links up to an element which I believe would look like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">Some content that should be hidden</div>
```

And finally make sure you have jQuery in your HTML page - use this code in your `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

And now your code should be working.

Comment: I would guess `$("#myDiv").toggle(foo_pdf || foo_jpg);` would be ok too, likely no need to actually remove it from the DOM

Comment: Oh yes, thanks @mplungjan! Although the OP did want to remove the element which is why I'm doing it in my answer, but that's the other alternative.